# How to set minimum width under developer options only for specific apps?

Tags: screen

My device is a Samsung Galaxy A40 running Android 10 (but it probably doesn't matter that much in this case)

I want an app to think that my screen is the size of a tablet, because in that app it might be beneficial to have larger screen size. I went to developer settings, and under "Minimum width" , I changed the default value which was 360 dp, to 800 dp. Now the app thinks my display is larger, and it gives me a slightly better interface. However, the only problem is that now the rest of the OS also thinks that this is my screen size.

Is there any way to set the "minimum width" only for that app, and not the rest of the Android interface?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I believe it to be a global setting. Related when developers had to use `adb` to set such values: [Android: How to use “adb shell wm” to simulate other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19922688/295004)